# Editting a moderated question on android

Tags: support

How can i tell if a moderator editted my question on android?

I want to edit it but ill get in punishment if i try and edit it in case moderator had recently editted it.

Im told to make the question more clear so im trying to do that but first need to know if moderator says it's okay before trying

This stuff is so confusing and difficult

Is there a messaging system or anything that a moderator can contact me thru in order to let me know that i have a green light to try and ask my question more clearly?

Or should i just make a new meta post every tike i want to edit a question?

Comment: I went ahead and editted it again.  I hope im not punished for this.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i tell if a moderator editted my question on android?

All edits made to the question appear in the edit history, whether they are made by a moderator or not. However, it seems that the edit history is not viewable in the Android app. There is a [feature request to add it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228440/add-the-revision-history-to-the-android-app).

Incidentally,

> I want to edit it but ill get in punishment if i try and edit it in case moderator had recently editted it.

this is not true. You don't get punished for editing a question further after a moderator's edit.